# How to chain new work to already enqueued work with WorkManager?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

Let's say we have two workers: `WorkerA` and `WorkerB`. Now `WorkerB` can't be started before `Worker` is finished. Normally we would chain these two workers:

```
WorkManager.getInstance()
    .beginWith(workA)
    .then(workB)
    .enqueue()
```

But the problem is the we don't know exact moment when we can start `WorkerB` (we only that that it has to wait for `WorkerA`).

There are actually two cases:

1. We want to start `WorkerB` when `WorkerA` has started, but it's not finished yet.
2. We want to start `WorkerB` after `WorkerA` has finished.

In a perfect world, `WorkManager` would have an option to rather wait for some work or to chain to already existing work.

I thought about starting `WorkerB` from `WorkerA` before it will end doing job, but I'm not sure if accessing `WorkManager` from Work before returning `Result` is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a chain of work, `WorkerB` will only start after `WorkerA` has completed successfully. If `WorkerA` fails, then `WorkerB` will also be marked as a failure.

If you want to start `WorkerB` when `WorkerA` has started, you can just enqueue `WorkerB` in `WorkerA`'s `doWork()` method. Please keep in mind that both Workers are decoupled at that point.